# how does google-cloud-function generate function-execution-id?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

A Cloud Function triggered by an HTTP request has a corresponding function-execution-id for each calling request (in the request and response header). It is used for tracing and viewing the log of a specific request in Stack Driver Logging. In my case, it is a string of 12 characters. When I continuously do HTTP requests to a cloud function and see the function-execution-id, I get the result below:

```
j8dorcyxyrwb
j8do4wolg4i3
j8do8bxu260m
j8do2xhqmr3s
j8dozkdlrjzp
j8doitxtpt29
j8dow25ri4on
```

On each line, the first 4 characters are the same "j8do" but the rest are different, so I wonder what is the structure of function-execution-id.

How was it generated?

Answer (score 0):

The execution id is opaque, meaning that it doesn't contain any useful data. It is just a unique ID.  How it was generated should not be of any issue to you, the consumer.  From examination, it looks like it might be some time-based value similar to [UUIDv1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)), but any code that you write that consumes these IDs should make no assumptions about how they were generated.